# Unable to run my Sails.js application using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sails.js

Unable to run my application using Postgresql on my sails application.

I have a running postgresql on my local server.

Would you know how to fix below error? I've tried logging the datastore value in node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:372:10 and the datastore is really undefined.

> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
>   error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
>   : Could not run `describe` due to 1 validation error:
>   • `datastore` is a required input- but it was not
>   defined.

I have below postgres connection defined in my config folder.

```
module.exports.connections = {
      postgres: { 
        adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'postgres',
        password: '',
        database: 'databasename'
      }
}
```

Node version: v6.8.0
Sails version: 0.12.7
sails-postgresql version: 1.0.0-9

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `port` parameter is missing. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-postgresql) is a brief documentation.

I hope this could help you